# Break stream of digits into smaller chunks for processing

Tags: c#

Please understand the problem I am going to present is academic and as such may not make sense in a real world application.

I have a sample program that functions properly. This program writes data to a file in which every line is a byte. The lines are numeric representations of these bytes. This numeric representation is the result of 128 bit RSA encryption of the bytes.

For example the very first line:

> 96044789616462297850953361101470572607 translates (decrypts) into 60 and byte 60 is of course **<**  which is correct as this is an xml doc.

Now the sample program has a distinct advantage as the encrypted source file has line breaks in all the correct spots.

My self-inflicted pursuit was to try and instead read from a stream of digits. So where the sample program reads 4 lines and process each one:

```
96044789616462297850953361101470572607 == 60 == <
40994093243674456311017847789777907446  == 63 == ?
61444338813524296592539084778436332638  == 120 == x
169017452170450092162160631302176410189  == 109 == m
//Note how the fourth line is 39 not 38 digits
```

I would instead have:

```
960447896164622978509533611014705726074099409324367445631101784778977790744661444338813524296592539084778436332638169017452170450092162160631302176410189......
```

Now originally I thought to split on every 38th digit:

```
lineSplitted = Enumerable.Range(0, (line.Length / 38)).Select(l => line.Substring(l * 38, 38)).ToArray();
```

but as mentioned above that isn't a guaranteed delimiter. So it seems that I must inject a delimiter as the stream is built. For example a palindrome like 1971791 that I could recognize and use for my splits when reading.

Is this the proper approach to this problem of identifying and plucking each encrypted segment out of the stream for decryption?

---

Edit:

So it seems from the comments a delimiter is the approach to use. Following @usr suggestion to avoid a numeric delimiter I use the split | and it of course base64 encodes and decodes just fine.

Comment: So; you are taking the line-delimited file and building a secondary; non-line delimited stream to read from? Would you consider just parsing the line-delimited file into a collection and reading from that?

Comment: Well if I stayed local that could work. But my sandbox scenario was to produce a stream to send elsewhere and the receiver be able to process it.

Comment: Are you willing to use a non-digit delimiter?; A palindrome is not guaranteed to now show up naturally in the stream. It seems to me that no sequence of digits is a safe delimiter.

Comment: Why not send it off in chunks (ie. one or two bytes at a time). Then you don't need a "stream"?

Comment: @usr Definitely willing to use something other than a digit delimiter as I saw the same potential problem as you suggest.

Comment: So would a `Split('|')` work for you? That's so easy that it might be cheating.

Comment: @usr I used split with success! Thank You. Make the comment an answer so I can mark it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you willing to use a non-digit delimiter? Consider using `Split('|')`.